# Mongodb normal exit before applying a write lock

Tags: mongodb, scrapy

I am using python, scrapy, MongoDB for my web scraping project. I used to scrape 40Gb data daily. Is there a way or setting in mongodb.conf file so that MongoDB will exit normally before applying a write lock on db due to disk full error ?

Because every time i face this problem of disk full error in MongoDB. Then I have to manually re-install MongoDB to remove the write lock from db. I cant run repair and compact command on the database because for running this command also I need free space.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't handle disk-full errors very well in certain cases, but you do not have to uninstall and then re-install MongoDB to remove the lock file. Instead, you can just `mongod.lock` file from this. As long as you have journalling enabled, your data should be good. Of course, at that moment, you can't add more data to the MongoDB databases.

You probably wouldn't need `repair` and `compact` only helps if you actually have deleted data from MongoDB. `compact` does **not** compress data, so this is only useful if you indeed have deleted data.

Constant adding, and then deleting later can cause fragmentation and lots of disk space to be unused. You can prevent that mostly by using the `userPowerOf2Sizes` [option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes) that you can set on collections. `compact` mitigates this by rewriting the database files as well, but as you said you need free disk space for this. I would advice you to also add some monitoring to warn you when your data size reaches 50% of your full disk space. In that case, there is still plenty of time to use `compact` to reclaim unused space.

Comment: Removing mongod.lock file dosent helps in mycase it appears again.

Comment: How to add monitoring servie for mongodb because all my scraping work is performed by cronjob

Comment: It appears again if MongoDB is started, sure. It's supposed to do that. For monitoring, you can use something like this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html — but that's outside the scope of your question.